# ¿como puedo iniciar sesison de forma manual en un navegador de selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Traté de iniciar sesión pero me sale un error, ¿alguien sabe por qué?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

url = "https://www.nike.cl/login"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension',False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation",'enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(999)
driver.quit()
```

[image: el error]

En otras ocasiones me deniegan el acceso, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

lo que hago practicamente es abrir la web y de forma manual inicio en mi cuenta pero me aparece ese error, antes no me dejaba porque salia que estaba siendo controlado por un software lo logre sacar y ahora ese error.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de [es.so], la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [ask]. Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: disculpa, ahí lo edite.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre solucionar agregando el argumento ->

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```